# Compute the following limit of the integral

Tags: real-analysis, integration, lebesgue-integral

Compute

$$\lim_{n \to \infty} \int_{0}^{1} \frac{n^4u^2e^{-nu}}{1 + n^2u}du$$

I'm in a class where we are discussing Lebesgue measure, and we have not discussed the dominated convergence theorem. We have learned the BND and Monotone convergence theorems though. I'm trying to do the integral in general with elementary techniques, but I'm not sure that one can. I'm also not exactly sure which theorem I can apply to move the limit inside, nor what the limit of the middle term would be. Can anyone lend a hand and get me started?

Comment: Just wait until the DCT.

Comment: @uniquesolution is there a way to do it without? We were asked to complete it.

Answer (score 1):

Hint: Let $u=v/n.$ The integral becomes

$$\int_0^n \frac{nv}{1+nv}ve^{-v}\,dv= \int_0^\infty \left(\frac{nv}{1+nv}\chi_{(0,n)}(v)\right )ve^{-v}\,dv. $$

Comment: what are you using to get to the second equality? I see you put $\chi$ in there, but I'm not sure how you did that. I'm wondering if this problem is indeed above my level right now.

Comment: If you know the MCT, then this is not above your level. Recall that in the MCT the domain is fixed. A simple maneuver to accomplish that is to write $\int_0^n f_n$ as $\int_0^\infty f_n\chi_{(0,n)}.$

Comment: Oh yeah because the limit moving inside means the n becomes infinity. Ok that makes sense. But now, I still have no idea how to continue from there.

Comment: Show $\dfrac{nv}{1+nv}\chi_{(0,n)}(v)$ is pointwise increasing on $(0,\infty).$

Comment: I'm not convinced it is. The denominator will grow faster due to the + 1. So I think it would be decreasing since $\chi$ is either 0 or 1.